# how to two specific date and time subtraction or addition in unix bash shell

Tags: bash, datetime, unix, addition, subtraction

for example , below example is simple. 
    DATE=$(date -v-7d )
    echo $DATE

but  how to calculate

```
2019-02-28 00:00:00  - or +  01:30:00 # date&time - or +  time
```

or

```
2019-02-28 00:00:00  - or + 2019-02-20 13:30:35 # date&time - or + date&time
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 date; date --date="5 hours ago 55 minutes ago 40 seconds ago " +%H%M-%d%m%Y
```

In this way you can add or subtract from the current time

Comment: does't works in unix terminal with bash .

Comment: It does if you have the same version of the `date` command. Which OS or shell you use doesn't really matter for this. The options look like GNU `date`, which is standard on most Linux platforms, and easy to install on basically every other system. If you require compatibility with e.g. BSD `date` (which is what you get out of the box on e.g. MacOS) or Busybox, you shoud probably say so.

Comment: for example ,  
BSD / UNIX    : date -v-7d

Comment: LINUX   : date -d-"7days" 
so different many options

Comment: please let me know  not from current time but  from specific date& time for + or - operations .